# CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217 while using Microsoft-graph-auth 0.2.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We are using the following libraries:

- microsoft-sdk-java-auth 0.2.0
- microsoft-graph 2.3.1
- microsoft-graph-core 1.0.5

```
    java.util.List<String> scopes = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(); scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"); 
    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientId, scopes, clientSecret, tenantId, NationalCloud.Global);
    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient(); 
    User user = graphClient.users(emailAddress).buildRequest().get();
```

We get this error sometimes while fetching any user's details.
ex- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/email-addr@domain.com

> Trace: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code:
> InvalidAuthenticationToken Error message: CompactToken parsing failed
> with error code: 80049217
>
> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/email-addr@domain.com
> SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.1 Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
>
> 401 : Unauthorized
> com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromConnection(GraphServiceException.java:501)
> at
> com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.handleErrorResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:503)
> at
> com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:423)
> at
> com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:220)
> at
> com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:200)
> at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:345) at
> com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.UserRequest.get(UserRequest.java:171)

Comment: Seems like you are unauthorized. Make sure that your credentials are valid.

Comment: Hello Victor. Can you share the access token?

Comment: Also, if you have a request id and timestamp that could help.

Comment: Credentials are valid. It is working sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. I can't share the access token since it is being fetched by new microsoft graph auth library